# Problem configuring output S3 bucket for allowing AWS Transcribe to store transcription results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-transcribe

I am trying to configure a job transcription within AWS Transcribe so that the result is automatically stored in a S3 Bucket.

```
aws transcribe start-transcription-job --transcription-job-name testingTranscription \
--language-code pt-BR \
--media-format wav \
--media MediaFileUri=s3://[BUCKET_NAME]/audio.wav \ 
--output-bucket-name s3://[BUCKET_NAME]/
```

I get the following message:

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the StartTranscriptionJob operation: 1 validation error detected: Value 's3://[BUCKET_NAME]/' at 'outputBucketName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-z0-9][\.\-a-z0-9]{1,61}[a-z0-9]
```

It says something about regular expression pattern, but I think it is a permissions problem. I am not able to figure out how to set this permissions using IAM because when I try to create a Role for the service, it does not appear in the list:

[Service list available for roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URHSJ.png)

The documentation says: "If you use your S3 bucket, you must grant Amazon Transcribe write access."

How can I do this if the service does not accept a role?

Answer (score 1):

The bucket name should simply be a string containing the bucket name. For example:

```sh
aws transcribe start-transcription-job --transcription-job-name testingTranscription \
--language-code pt-BR \
--media-format wav \
--media MediaFileUri=s3://my-input-bucket/audio.wav \ 
--output-bucket-name my-output-bucket
```

Comment: Thanks!!! That's it. Everywhere else we use s3://, but here just the bucket name. Lost an hour or so in this little inconsistency.